# SPO: when a document is added in library, then create an item in a different list

Tags: spfx, remote-event-receiver, sharepoint-framework

My senario is like this: when a user uploads a document in a document library in SPO, then a new item is created in another list with some information from the document which was uploaded.

On premises we got event receivers, for SharePoint online we got remove event receivers. My question is: can this be done using SharePoint framework or SPFx extensions instead of Remote event receivers? Any suggestion is welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

One more option you can try would be a workflow on document library. This workflow would trigger on adding / uploading new document and you can insert new item in other list.

All the best!!!

Comment: are you talking about a SharePoint Workflow or a Microsoft Flow? Which one would be best for this scenario?

Comment: I think SharePoint designer workflow would be best option

Answer (score 1):

The SharePoint FrameWork only allows for:

- Provisioning Lists and Content-Types
- Creating client side webparts
- Creating application customizers which are

  - JS code on every page with potential placeholders
  - custom list actions
  - custom field rendering

It is not capable of executing server-side code, so event-receivers (event remote) are another topic.

Shridhar J Joshi's answer should fit your question since it represents the code-less alternative of an event receiver.

Hope this helps!